# How to lazy init a global var?

Tags: c++, constants, global, lazy-initialization

I'm making a DLL. I want to have a unique global var (in my case, a `IBitmap` struct), within a namespace, for each Compilation Unit that will include `MyTools.h`. This is my the code within `MyTools.h`:

```
namespace MyTools
{
    const IBitmap BITMAP_CONTROL_BACKGROUND;
}
```

Which init an "empty" var. I want to init this variable calling a method (that return a `IBitmap`) of MyClass (which will be instanciated later), but when I do this prior to each process which will use this var:

```
BITMAP_CONTROL_BACKGROUND = myClass->LoadIBitmap(CONTROL_BACKGROUND, CONTROL_BACKGROUND_PATH, 1);
```

the compiler tell me that `BITMAP_CONTROL_BACKGROUND` is const, so I can't to it.

What's the (best) way to init later and keep the var global?

Comment: Lookup the Singleton design pattern and it's implementations in C++.

Comment: @ilotXXI: Singleton is for `class`. I just need namespace/vars, not a whole Class,.

Comment: Remove the const, use a pointer (smartpointer), initialize on creation with null so you can check if it already was initialized. Initialize the pointer as needed...

Comment: Solution: Don't use global state ;)

Comment: @SimonKraemer: I can't remove `const`. `IBitmap *BITMAP_CONTROL_BACKGROUND;` will give to me Linker error, because it is already defined when I include many times the same .h

Comment: Why does `myClass` load the bitmap? May it be exchanged by static loader?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson: Not using something like `std::cout` doesn't seem practical. Neither does it seem practical to avoid defining something like `std::cout`, if it fits the purpose.

Comment: @ilotXXI: this is how the framework I'm using was created. Here the IBitmap declaration: https://github.com/majek/wdl/blob/master/WDL/IPlug/IPlugStructs.h#L9 and here the LoadBitmap function https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/master/WDL/IPlug/IGraphics.cpp#L423

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me tell you to **do not do it**. You're using a global variable (with another one to initialize it...) then it's simply Bad™. Yes, you do not want to share that variable between compilation units but it makes it even more weird (IMO).

---

If you're still reading and I didn't convince you to don't do it then you can use a function to initialize a `const` expression. Put everything in your header file:

```
#pragma once

namespace MyTools {
    namespace Impl {
        IBitmap InitializeControlBackground();
    }

    const IBitmap BITMAP_CONTROL_BACKGROUND(Impl::InitializeControlBackground());
}

IBitmap MyTools::Imp::InitializeControlBackground() {
    return myClass->LoadIBitmap(CONTROL_BACKGROUND, CONTROL_BACKGROUND_PATH, 1);
}
```

Few notes:

- `InitializeControlBackground()` is declared in nested implementation `Impl` namespace to do not pollute `MyTools` namespace.
- If `InitializeControlBackground()` may be different for each compilation unit then simply move it to .cpp instead of .h.

Comment: Why "do not do it"? If I need to init the same object shared across the "future" objects, why this would create a pain?

Comment: first hit of "evils of global variables" - http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad is probably worth a read

Comment: Because each and every shared object increases dependencies and coupling. A global variable might be accessed by literally anywhere then each (uncontrolled) access will be coupled with all the others (and it may open your code to race conditions).

Comment: That's not my example! Here I'm defining "global" tool that define a specific element that come from a sort of "tools" that I can use (and never edit) everywhere. I'm working on this framework, which use many types this approch: https://github.com/majek/wdl/blob/master/WDL/IPlug/IPlugStructs.h#L30

Comment: As you can see, every COLOR_ elements are global, and I can call it when I want. In the case of IBitmap, I want to do the same, but I need to init them using such a function within a class that will be init later.

Comment: I'm not saying you won't see global variables in real-world code. However to be pretty common won't make them _good_. For color, for example, why they didn't define those constants inside a Color class? Instead of COLOR_RED you'd write Color::RED. Anyway constants like colors are somehow tricky because they're globals even if defined inside a class but we really can't completely avoid them. Your case is more subtle because initialization isn't a constexpr but it accesses another global object. That object is  now coupled to every single compilation unit that will include this header.

Comment: Don't take me wrong, often (not always) there is another better way to do the same thing and avoid them. For the reasons just read UKMonkey's linked article. If you want to keep these globals then just use proposed solution, it works regardless I agree with their usage or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here can be used a casual singleton, but you need to provide a factory object to initialize the instance. If you can create `myClass` any time:

```
// Header file.
namespace MyTools
{
    const IBitmap * bitmapControlBackground();
}

// Source file.
const IBitmap * MyTools::bitmapControlBackground()
{
    // Here is a casual singleton. If multi-thread access is possible,
    // here must be a casual way to solve it with mutex.
    static const IBitmap instance = MyClass().LoadBitmap(...);
    return &instance;
}
```

If you have a global `myClass` variable:

```
// Source file.
const IBitmap * MyTools::bitmapControlBackground()
{
    // Here is a casual singleton. If multi-thread access is possible,
    // here must be a casual way to solve it with mutex.
    static const IBitmap instance = myClass->LoadBitmap(...);
    return &instance;
}
```

Otherwise you have to pass it on each call:

```
// Header file.
namespace MyTools
{
    const IBitmap * bitmapControlBackground(MyClass *creator);
}

// Source file.
const IBitmap * MyTools::bitmapControlBackground(MyClass *creator)
{
    // Here is a casual singleton. If multi-thread access is possible,
    // here must be a casual way to solve it with mutex.
    static const IBitmap instance = creator->LoadBitmap(...);
    return &instance;
}
```